# Sound effect that quiets other audio iOS AVAudio

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudiosession

I want to have a sound effect in my iOS that, if other audio is playing (such as iTunes) quiets any other audio is playing and plays over top of it. I know
    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers

Will mix the sounds together, but I want mine to be able to be heard clearly. I've seen this done in the RunKeeper app (when the lady describes your run to you it quiets your music) but I can not find it in Apple's Documentation.

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation says this only works with PlayAndRecord, but it works.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error: nil];
```